# How to create a dynamic query using php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+------------+
| id | id_post | code_table |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 34523   | 1          |
| 2  | 3453    | 4          |
| 3  | 43434   | 2          |
| 4  | 54321   | 1          |
| 5  | NULL    | NULL       |
| 6  | 32411   | 2          |
| 7  | 42313   | 1          |
| 8  | 34242   | 2          |
+----+---------+------------+
//                    ^ all of my focus is on this column
```

Also I have this array:

```
$convert_code_name = array (
                        "1" => "Post1", 
                        "2" => "Post2", 
                        "3" => "Post3",
                        "4" => "Post4"  
                           );
```

Now **I want to create this**:

```
$query = "select * from post1
             union all
          select * from post2
             union all
          select * from post4";

          // there isn't "post3", because 3 isn't exist in the code_table column
```

How can I do that?

---

Here is **my try**:

```
// connect to database
$stm = $db->prepare('select * from mytable');
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetch();

/* array_unique: removes duplicate values
   array_filter: removes "NULL" values */

array_filter(array_unique($result[code_table]), function($item) {
    return $item != 'NULL';
});

foreach($item as $numb){
    $query .= 'select * from'.$convert_code_name[$numb].'union all';
}
```

But I don't know why my code doesn't work, How can I do that?

Comment: I think you just want an `in` list.

Comment: `array_filter` returns a new array, you need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: `$result` just contains the first row of the table. Did you mean to use `fetchAll`?

Comment: @Barmar honestly I don't know, maybe I need to `fetchAll` .. I just understand (so far) it is better to I use `DISTINCT` (mysql layer) instead of `array_unique()` (php layer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the query to get unique values, so you don't need to call `array_unique`.

Then, once you have all the values, you can use `implode` to connect all the `SELECT` queries with `UNION ALL`.

```
$stm = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT code_table FROM mytable WHERE code_table IS NOT NULL");
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll();
// This returns a 2-dimensional array, we just want one column
$results = array_column($results, 'code_table');

$query = implode(' UNION ALL ', array_map(function($code_table) use ($convert_code_name) {
    return "SELECT * FROM " . $convert_code_name[$code_table];
}, $results));
```

Comment: Oh Dear Lord ...! I don't know what should I say .. Perfect. +1

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed to ping you again, but ..., Look your code seems completely correct. But I don't know why it doesn't execute ..! My php version is old (5.2.6). I think `array_map(function($code_table)` part has a problem with my php version. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You have to use `create_function` in that old version. Exercise for the reader, I don't have time to show it.

Comment: It also doesn't have `array_column`, that's from PHP 5.5. Read the documentation for a shim.

Comment: I'm amazed it has PDO.

Comment: I don't know what you said is sarcasm or not .. But it support PDO as well.

Comment: Well I installed a new php version and your code executed ..! all fine. Just you forgot to remove `NULL` values ..., The output is like this: `SELECT * FROM Post1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Post2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Post3 SELECT * FROM `

Comment: Sorry about that -- added `WHERE code_table IS NOT NULL` to the query now.

Comment: I know writing a unrelated comment under a post isn't a good thing. But I really need to know your opinion about something (I will remove this comment after a short while). Well, here is a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735047/how-to-use-case-function-in-order-by?noredirect=1#34735122) and here is a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#comment57260658_34734437), May you please tell me which one is right?

Comment: @stack I haven't looked at it closely, but Gordon knows his stuff and is one of the few who finds errors in my SQL answers. To make variables in a query work reliably when order is important, you can do the assignment in a subquery that has its own `ORDER BY` clause that doesn't depend on the variable.

Comment: Ah, well all my target of using variables is {Not using `join`}. Because I have tested, [using variables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41eb22/1) is much faster that [joining table with itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#34734437). Now I'm confuse, which one is better? *(performance is really important for me)*

Comment: Can I use `$query` next to `JOIN`?

Comment: Also [here is my full-code](http://pastebin.com/KnTcjSwg). It works. But it takes a lot of time for huge data. Can I make it faster?

Comment: A query like this can't make use of indexes on the `postN` tables. It might be better to do the join with each table, and then combine those results in the union.

Comment: Ah ok, My friend *(that he and me work on the same project)* asked that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270024/how-to-use-a-select-statement-into-join-clause). And there is two answers. May you please tell me which one is better?

Comment: The answer from StanislavL is just what I said in my comment above. I don't think the other answer will make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query .= 'select * from'.$convert_code_name[$numb].'union all';
```

will generate wrong sql, change it to (I assume that $convert_code_name[$numb] contains full table name like Post1, Post2):

```
$query = '';
foreach($item as $numb){
    $query .= ($query!=''?' union all ':'') . 'select * from '.$convert_code_name[$numb];
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I **don't** select `NULL` values in the query?

Comment: @stack `where field is not null`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to first execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code_table FROM events
```

Then you can build your second query like from its result, which only contains 1 row for each existing `code_table`.