# How to sort results order by timestamp except one of them?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | Type | AcceptedAnswerId | timestamp |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | question1          | 0    | 3                | 1         |
| 2  | answer1            | 1    | NULL             | 2         |
| 3  | answer2            | 1    | NULL             | 3         | -- accepted answer
| 4  | answer3            | 1    | NULL             | 4         |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
```

Now I want this result: *(please focus on the order)*

```
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | Type | AcceptedAnswerId | timestamp |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | question1          | 0    | 3                | 1         |
| 3  | answer2            | 1    | NULL             | 3         | -- accepted answer 
| 2  | answer1            | 1    | NULL             | 2         |
| 4  | answer3            | 1    | NULL             | 4         |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
//                          ^ 0 means question and 1 means answer
```

Well how can I do that? (I want something exactly like SO sorting)

---

Here is my try:

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE 1 ORDER BY Type, {I need to add something here}, timestamp
```

Comment: What criteria do you have to know that id 2 should be first??  That part is not clear to me in your question.

Comment: @Clayton . . . Because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Clayton Gordon Linoff right, btw id 2 shouldn't be first, id 3 should be first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself to determine which row is the accepted answer.  Then the information can be used in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Mytable t LEFT JOIN
     Mytable tans
     ON t.id = tans.AcceptedAnswerId
ORDER BY t.Type,
         (tans.id IS NOT NULL) DESC,
         t.timestamp
```

Comment: Well thanks, +1. But seems expensive, I think if I set `1` in the  `AcceptedAnswerId` column for accepted answer, I can just do this: `ORDER BY type, AcceptedAnswerId, timestamp`. What you think?

Comment: @stack . . . You should ask another question with better detail on your actual tables and desired results.  Changing your question now is rude, because it can invalidate the answer which draws downvotes.

Comment: I accepted your solution as my answer. Also as far as I know about you, you are a really professional programmer in database cases *(I always enjoy of your solutions)*, But in this case, I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41eb22/1) solution is much better than yours, I linked that fiddle to you just because I know you are interesting to learn new things, So no offence.

Comment: BTW, your [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41eb22/2) doesn't work ... *(However people can get the main idea of your answer)*

Comment: @stack . . . Your answer is using variables in the `order by`.  As far as I know, there is no guarantee whatsoever about the order of how the variable will be assigned.  Just because this might work in one case does not mean that it is a general solution.  (If you have documentation that says that using variables in the `order by` is safe and deterministic, then please share that information).

Comment: @GordonLinoff What is the difference when you use variable to emulate row_number? why is safe there? Can you point me to something I should read to understand when is ok use variable and when doesnt.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please edit your solution: `... ON tans.AcceptedAnswerId = t.id ...`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . You should start with the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).  There are enough caveats on how variables are handled; you should be very careful about putting a variable anywhere other than a single expression in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Yes, I read that multiple times, but still not clear to me where is the danger and how to solve it. Like on the row_number() I think the multiple `IF` is to make sure the evaluation is on the order we need, so even Im not sure why I just follow the lead. But now in this case you say have to be carefull so looks like you dont have a way to solve it here and now Im more curious.

Comment: Do you think, keeping both questions and answers in the same table is a bad structure (design)?