# MS SQL What does = '%' and '%%%' mean when in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a vendor's database that the company I work for, they have some expressions that I don't think I have ever seen:

```
FROM CO_ITEM_MASTER WHERE smartpart_num = '%'
```

I have seen  `= '%Text%'` 
and I know what that means, but if there is no text along with the `'%'` what does that mean?

I also have the following:

```
AND (lower(CO_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_NUM) like lower('%%%')
```

What does the `'%%%'` mean when there is no text between the `''` characters?

Comment: Is your first expression actually supposed to be `smartpart_num LIKE '%'` rather than `= '%'`?

Comment: `%` is usually used for a wildcard in conjunction with `LIKE`. For example, `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE name LIKE 'A%'` would return all companies with a name that starts with `A`. In your first expression, it is looking for items where the part number is literally equal to `%` because it is using `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: I haven't seen `%%%` used before. `%` matches any number of characters. Perhaps they were trying to match part numbers consisting of exactly 3 chars? If that's the case, they should have used the underscore `_` wildcard instead.

Comment: Michael, I have to assume it is supposed to be as it is written.  It was written by a vendor and I do not know enough about what it does to go past that.

Comment: It's possible that the vendor thinks that's the code for finding an actual `%` symbol in a string. But the syntax for that would be something like `LIKE '%[%]%'`

Answer (score 3):

[% means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> Match Any string of zero or more characters.

Because a zero length string matches this can be repeated as many times as desired without affecting the semantics and will return any row where `ITEM_NUM` is not `NULL`.

It is of course pointless to use more than one, perhaps this is code generated by code rather than a human.

Comment: @AlvinThompson - It answers `What does the '%%%' mean?` Nothing special. The same as `%`. Repeating the `%` n times will still match the same thing as `n * 0 = 0`

Comment: I know writing a unrelated comment under a post isn't a good thing. But I really need to know your opinion about something *(I will remove this comment after a short while)*. Well, here is a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735047/how-to-use-case-function-in-order-by?noredirect=1#34735122) and here is a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#comment57260658_34734437), May you please tell me which one is right?