# How to use CASE function in ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My friend asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them) a few times ago. Also there is a answer under that and it is good, but not for my case. The idea of that solution is joining the current table to itself. That seems expensive and not effective for me, Because in reality there is four `join` on these tables (`votes`, `favorites`, `comments`, `viewed`) in my query.

Now I want to know, how can I do that using `CASE` function? Something like this:

```
... ORDER BY Type, CASE WHEN AcceptedAnswerId = Id THEN 1 ELSE 0, timestamp
```

Or is there any better solution?

---

To be more readable, I paste those examples here:

I have a table like this:

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | Type | AcceptedAnswerId | timestamp |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | question1          | 0    | 3                | 1         |
| 2  | answer1            | 1    | NULL             | 2         |
| 3  | answer2            | 1    | NULL             | 3         | -- accepted answer
| 4  | answer3            | 1    | NULL             | 4         |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
```

Now I want this result: *(please focus on the order)*

```
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | Type | AcceptedAnswerId | timestamp |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | question1          | 0    | 3                | 1         |
| 3  | answer2            | 1    | NULL             | 3         | -- accepted answer 
| 2  | answer1            | 1    | NULL             | 2         |
| 4  | answer3            | 1    | NULL             | 4         |
+----+--------------------+------+------------------+-----------+
//                          ^ 0 means question and 1 means answer
```

Comment: Can you include the SQL you're currently trying to use with your question?

Comment: @VolkerK That schema is incomplete. In reality there is a `related` column which links related question and answers together.

Comment: @VolkerK Why did you delete your answer? Your fiddle was great ..! Anyway I have a small question about your fiddle. As I said in reality I have a column named `related` with determine related posts together. Now I fill that column with the `id` of question. I mean is that column for all answers plus the question fills of question's id. Is that ok? or I can store something else to link related posts *(question and answers)* ?

Comment: @VolkerK I see, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no more thoughts on this issue.

Comment: @VolkerK I think you have to *undelete* your answer .. [Because...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#comment57260658_34734437)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE would work, but you are missing the `END`.  But in this case, you could also just use `IF(AcceptedAnswerId = Id,1,0)`.

In the simple case you show, you *could* just do:

```
order by type,if(type=0,(@accepted:=acceptedanswerid),id<>@accepted),timestamp
```

but I don't know if that would work in your real case.

Comment: I added `END` in the end of `CASE` function and now there isn't any syntax error. thanks. But still sorting doesn't work. I want this order: 1.question, 2. accepted answer 3. other answers according to `timestamp`. How can I do that?

Comment: by joining, as shown in the answer to the other question.  or change your data, so that there is some column in the answer that shows that it is accepted.  or keep questions and answers in separate tables; that seems to be the root of your problem.

Comment: emm maybe add a new column to shows accepted answers could be fine. But what do you think? Joining that big table to itself or add a new column for that purpose?

Comment: Oh one thing, can I do that using a sub-query? Is would be better?

Comment: are you getting just the answers for a single question in this query?  with proper indexes, how much data is in the rest of the table isn't relevant.   no, sub-queries are rarely better.

Comment: Can you please tell me `type` and `acceptedanswerid` need to get index in this line? `if(type=0,(@accepted:=acceptedanswerid),id<>@accepted)`

Comment: no; it just saves the accepted answer id when it sees the question and then compares to that when looking at the answers.  but I repeat, this may not work in your actual case that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I repeat, it works perfectly for me ..! But are you sure `type` doesn't need to be index? My friend told me everything is one side of `=`, it needs to be index, so look this : `.. type=0 ..`, Still you believe that column doesn't need to index?

Comment: You can start with [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html). The result of that query might be even worth another question, maybe even on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Show us your whole schema and query and we can talk about indexes.  Putting indexes on everything on the left side of = often makes mysql do some horrific index_merge query plans and is a very very bad idea.

Comment: May please read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#comment57260658_34734437) and tell your opinion about it? Waiting for you ...! I hope you reject it ...

Comment: yes, using variables in the order by makes it dependent on the order the rows are initially read, before sorting.  that's one of the reasons I am emphasizing my solution will work only for the simple case you present, and not necessarily for your more complicated actual case.  I recommend you join.  And show us your real query and real schema (including indexes) so we can reassure you that it will be efficient or recommend changes to your indexing/query.

Comment: Ok, according to your recommendation I use `JOIN` ..! But I don't know why `JOIN` [doesn't work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41eb22/2) ... Really I don't know why.

Comment: So do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: I mean it isn't showing up; it just says "Loading..." and "Please build schema..." but the schema is empty

Comment: Ok [this structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e72e7) plus this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them/34734437?noredirect=1#34734437)

Comment: that join assumes the linking goes the other way.  this works (once type is set to 1 for questions!): `select t.* from mytable t left join mytable tquestion on t.type=1 and tquestion.acceptedanswerid=t.id order by t.type, tquestion.id is not null desc, t.timestamp` but could use an index on acceptedanswerid

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I think `t.type=1` is useless, am I right?

Comment: no, it keeps it from trying to look up if a question is the accepted answer.  but it doesn't change the results if you remove it

Comment: Sorry to ping you again .. as a consult: keeping both questions and answers in the same table is a bad design?

Answer (score 0):

Given the table definition (without proper indices) + sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Id` int, `QuestionOrAnswer` varchar(9), `Type` int, `AcceptedAnswerId` varchar(4), `related` int NOT NULL, `timestamp` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Id`, `QuestionOrAnswer`, `Type`, `AcceptedAnswerId`, `related`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
    (1, 'question1', 0, '3', 1, 1),
    (2, 'answer1', 1, NULL, 1, 2),
    (3, 'answer2', 1, NULL, 1, 3),
    (4, 'answer3', 1, NULL, 1, 4)
```

you can use the query

```
SELECT
  t2.*
FROM
  table1 as t1
JOIN
  table1 as t2
 ON
   t1.related=t2.related
 WHERE
   t1.related = 1
   AND t1.Type = 0
 ORDER BY
   t2.Type desc, t2.Id=t1.AcceptedAnswerId, t2.Id
```

to get the question/answer set of a specific question (`t1.related = 1` <- adjust that parameter for other questions).
And no, with the right indices this query is not "expensive".

example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24954/4 (yeah, took me 4 attempts to get it right, grrrrr)

Comment: Thanks, +1 ... But actually your solution is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734395/how-to-sort-results-order-by-timestamp-except-one-of-them#34734437), and I mentioned in my question that I don't want to join the table with itself. Because there is four joins on other tables and add a new join seems unopptimized.

Comment: "seems unopptimized" - why? Just arrange the JOINs in a way that the   intermediary resultset gets small fast.

Comment: Ok, lemme compare the performance of using `join` and using `if` *(like above answer)* and I will tell you why I said `join` is unopptimized.

Comment: To be hones there isn't a lot of difference. For 1000 requests, Your solution took 4.6sec and the above solution took 3.2sec ..! Anyway ok thanks

Comment: Yes, finally I came to this conclusion that using `join` in this case is the best option. But there is a big problem in your table-structure. I think it is impossible to write a query to `INSERT` a question. Why? Because we cannot fill `related` value exactly the same with its `id` value. Can we? How?

Comment: You can update the record. Or come up with a better table defintion/query.

Comment: Ok, I will update it using a trigger *(before insert)* ..! Just tell me is that design horrible? Or it is not bad .. `:-)`