# How to select all related rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+---------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | related |
+----+--------------------+---------+
| 1  | question1          | 0       |
| 2  | answer1            | 1       |
| 3  | answer2            | 1       |
| 4  | question2          | 0       |
| 5  | question3          | 0       |
| 6  | answer4            | 5       |
| 7  | answer4            | 4       |
| 8  | answer4            | 5       |
+----+--------------------+---------+
```

In the above table `0` means "question" and any number else means "answer". Also there is id-number of each question for its own answers in the `related` column. Now I want to know, how can I select the question plus all its own answers? Something like this:

For **question1:**

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+---------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | related |
+----+--------------------+---------+
| 1  | question1          | 0       |
| 2  | answer1            | 1       |
| 3  | answer2            | 1       |
+----+--------------------+---------+
```

For **question2:**

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+---------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | related |
+----+--------------------+---------+
| 4  | question2          | 0       |
| 7  | answer4            | 4       |
+----+--------------------+---------+
```

For **question3:**

```
// Mytable
+----+--------------------+---------+
| Id |  QuestionOrAnswer  | related |
+----+--------------------+---------+
| 5  | question3          | 0       |
| 6  | answer4            | 5       |
| 8  | answer4            | 5       |
+----+--------------------+---------+
```

And so on .. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from Mytable where id = 1 or related = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate a working example? I don't see how this will generate the desired output (e.g. the output for "question2" or "question3").

Comment: @showdev It's very simple, the `id = 1` part selects the question with id `1`, and the `related = 1` part selects answers which are related to the question with id `1`.

Comment: How does it output the question and answers for "question2"?

Comment: Well, do you think if I add a new column named `type` and set it `0` *(means question)* and `1` *(means answer)* and then fill `related` column  with question-id for both the question and all its own answers *(that means there isn't `0` value in `related` column anymore)*, is not better? *(because using `or` seems somewhat slow)*

Comment: @Alex Sounds like a good idea, you could then select both question and answers with only `where related = 1`.

Comment: I only said ["_Maybe_ you could even drop the Type field (related=0->question)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735047/how-to-use-case-function-in-order-by?noredirect=1#comment-57218023) ;-)