# How to use a SELECT statement into JOIN clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a variable which is containing a dynamic query. Something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, subject FROM post1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, subject FROM post2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, subject FROM post3";
```

Also I have this query:

```
SELECT code FROM mytable WHERE id = :id
```

Now I want to `join` query above with that dynamic query. Here is my try:

```
SELECT t1.code t2.subject FROM mytable t1 
   LEFT JOIN ($query) t2 ON t1.col = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = :id

/*
SELECT t1.code t2.subject FROM mytable t1
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, subject FROM post1
               UNION ALL
              SELECT id, subject FROM post2
               UNION ALL
              SELECT id, subject FROM post3) t2 ON t1.col = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = :id
*/
```

It works. But it takes a lot of time for huge data. How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.code t2.subject FROM mytable t1
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, subject FROM post1 
              JOIN mytable tt1 ON tt1.col = post1.id AND tt1.id=:id
               UNION ALL
              SELECT id, subject FROM post2
              JOIN mytable tt2 ON tt2.col = post2.id AND tt2.id=:id
               UNION ALL
              SELECT id, subject FROM post3
              JOIN mytable tt3 ON tt3.col = post3.id AND tt3.id=:id) t2 ON t1.col = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = :id
```

Just add the :id check to the internal querie4st to restrict amount of data selected.

Comment: May you please tell me your opinion about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270024/how-to-use-a-select-statement-into-join-clause#37271046)?

Comment: Also I think selecting `id` in sub queries is redundant, am I right?

Comment: Actually you JOIN ON the id

Comment: Ah ok, you are right .. And my last question, can I write `tt` instead of all those `tt1`, `tt2`, `tt3`? I've tested, it works. So, can I?

Comment: I think it's fine. I created disticnt aliases for the same table because I was not sure how aliases are interpreted with UNION ALL. If it works use tt

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query.

```
SELECT t1.code, t2.subject FROM (SELECT code, col FROM mytable WHERE id = :id ) t1 
 LEFT JOIN ($query) t2 ON t1.col = t2.id
```

Comment: col Should be in the select (SELECT code, col FROM mytable WHERE id = :id ). But anyway inner query **t2** retrieves all rows but we don't need them at all.

Comment: Yes we have to select col also in our select statement. Thanks @StanislavL

Comment: I think this will be executed essentially the same as the query in the question. Use `EXPLAIN` to see if there's any difference.